# How to create a related resource from a rails form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My project is about an online shopping site, using Ruby on Rails to buy phones.

My site has a page for adding a phone -  Samsung,Nokia...and in Samsung,it has many devices.
How do I to get the id of Samsung to create a new phone which is of type  'Samsung'.  Samsung is in the Products table, and phones is in Phones table.

```
class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phones
end
```

This is the action show of Product:

```
<h1>Your item</h1>

<h3><%= @product.name %></h4>
<% if logged_in?%>
    <% if current_user.admin? %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit',edit_product_path%>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
<%= link_to 'Home',welcome_home_path%>
<%= link_to 'New item',new_phone_path %> 
<%= link_to 'Create new phone',new_phone_path%> #It links to action new of Phones
```

But I cant get id of Product to do: `object_product.phones.create

```
class PhoneController < ApplicationController
  def new

  end
  def show
    @phone = Phone.find(params[:phone_id])
  end
  def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @phone = @product.phones.create(phone)
    redirect_to product_phone_path
  end
  private
    def phone
      params.require(:phone).permit(:name,:num)
    end
end
```

Comment: Hung, please review my edits and see if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a nested resources at your route, like following:

```
resources :product do
  resources :phone
end
```

and at your product view add this url helper `new_product_phone_path` instead of `new_phone_path`.

So now your your route for new would look like following:

```
/product/:product_id/phone/new
```

New controller:

```
def new
    @phone=Phone.new
end
```

Now if you have following in your form:

```
<%= form_for @phone do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br />

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Your controller action will look like something like following:

```
def create
    @phone=Phone.create(name: params[:name])
    @product=Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @product.phones << @phone
end
```

Comment: when I click to SamSung,it will show the action 'show',next i click create new phone,so why i can params[:product_name]

Comment: what does your route look like? is it like `products/:product_id/phone/new`

Comment: i tried to use Helper but it didn't seem to work.My Helper to get id of Product ( in this case is Samsung)

Comment: My route is phones/new.(After I click on Create new phone)

Comment: if that helps, then please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the tick mark just beside the answer and below the up and down arrow marks of voting.

Comment: Ok,thank you! I could do it.Now I don't know to find exactly ID of the device ( @phone=Phone.find(params[:id]) ? )